# Regex: Delete all empty lines between html tags <p> and </p>

Tags: regex

`<p>Fie pentru a păstra prospețimea anumitor culori (ex. odinioară, ullraniarinul. Text.`

`Altădată se folosea usturoiul, deoarece conține și un ulei esențial, rare aderă prin dizolvarea la suprafață a grăsimilor și lotodală un mucegaiul cleios, sensibil la apă.</p>`

**THE OUTPUT MUST BE:**

`<p>Fie pentru a păstra prospețimea anumitor culori (ex. odinioară, ullraniarinul. Text. Altădată se folosea usturoiul, deoarece conține și un ulei esențial, rare aderă prin dizolvarea la suprafață a grăsimilor și lotodală un mucegaiul cleios, sensibil la apă.</p>`

MY REGEX SEEMS TO BE GOOD in notepad++, BUT **I NEED A SHORTER REGEX** (because this one is not working on Python)

FIND: `(<p>)(.*?$)(\s+.*?)`

Replace by: `\1\2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a shorter regex that works in any case.

Here is a way that always works:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<p>|\G(?!\A))(?:(?!</p>).)*\K\R\h*`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:             # non capture group
    <p>             # literally
  |               # OR
    \G(?!\A)        # restart from last match position, not at the beginning of file
)               # end group
(?:             # non capture group
    (?!</p>)        # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't </p> after
    .               # any character but newline
)*              # end group, may appears 0 or more times
\K              # forget all we have seen until this position (reset operator)
\R              # any kind of line break
\h*             # 0 or more horizontal spaces
```

**Replacement:**

```
$0          # the whole match
:           # a colon
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: It is a very good regex @Toto. But I think Python does not recognize `\K` or `\A` or `\h`

Comment: @JustMe: May be. If you want to process HTML with Python, you'd better use a parser.

Comment: @JustMe: With Python, you can use `((?:<p>|\G(?!^))(?:(?!</p>).)*)\s+` and replace with: `\1` [Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vyvBcW/1)

Comment: FIND: `(?-si:<p>|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!"</p>).)*?\K\s+\s+`  REPLACE BY: (leave empty)

Answer (score 1):

FIND: `(^.*?)\s+\R\s+`

REPLACE BY: `\1` **or with** `\1\x20`

**OR**

FIND: `(<p>.*?$)\s+(.*?</p>)`

REPLACE BY: `\1 \2`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).